# AngularJS : child state return parent view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ui-sref

I'm using angularJs with ES6. Therefor each view are modules.

**Module project :**

```
let projectModule = angular.module('project', [
  uiRouter
])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('project', {
      url: '/projects/:origin/:owner/:name',
      template: '<project></project>',
      data : { pageTitle: 'Project' },
    });

})

.component('project', projectComponent)

.factory('$projectResource', service);
```

**Module alerts (its state is a child of project state) :**

```
let alertsModule = angular.module('alerts', [
  uiRouter
])

.config(($stateProvider) => {

  $stateProvider
    .state('project.alerts', {
      url: '/alerts',
      template: '<alerts></alerts>',
      data : { pageTitle: 'Alerts' }
    });

})

.component('alerts', alertsComponent);
```

All views are managed by the components and displayed from the defined template attribute in its related state.

```
<alerts></alerts>
```

**Components are defined as such :**

```
import template from './alerts.html';
import controller from './alerts.controller';
import './alerts.scss';

let alertsComponent = {

  restrict: 'E',
  template: template,
  controller: controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: true

};

export default alertsComponent;
```

**View is called that way :**

```
<a ui-sref="project.alerts({ origin: project.origin, owner: project.owner.name, name: project.name })">Alerts</a>
```

Or that way if i'm already in project :

```
<a ui-sref="project.alerts">Alerts</a>
```

Both href are correctly displaying :

> /projects/github/btribouillet/btproject/alerts

But i'm seing the the parent view :

```
<project></project>
```

While it should be :

```
<alerts></alerts>
```

What am i doing wrong? The solution until now was to have independent state from each others. But i'm trying to build a breadcrumb module and i'd like to be able to access to parent states. If states are independent from each others, this is not possible.

**Update:**

My main view is app.html :

```
<!-- Place all UI elements intended to be present across all routes in this file -->
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <navbar></navbar>
  <div class="view" ui-view></div>
  <navfooter></navfooter>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess would be that you forgot to put a ui-view directive in your "project" component html, so child state have no place to load in.

Comment: I'm gonna check that. I though this would not be necessary since it is 2 different views.

Comment: Indeed it was this, if you want to write it as an answer i'll be glad to validate it. Checked the doc https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-state-usage-examples

Comment: sure, I will do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put a ui-view directive in your "project" component html, so child state have no place to load in.