# AngularJs : Attach a stateParams value to custom data in state objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm defining a page title in my state object as advised [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects).

```
$stateProvider
  .state('project', {
    url: '/projects/:origin/:owner/:name',
    template: '<project></project>',
    data : { pageTitle: 'Project page title'},
  });
```

so i can access it this way later on:

```
$state.current.data.pageTitle
```

Now ... What i'd like to do is that instead of having a fixed value as pageTitle i'd like to access one the stateParams.

**BEWARE**, below exemple is not working, this is the way i'd like it to work.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('project', {
    url: '/projects/:origin/:owner/:name',
    template: '<project></project>',
    data : { pageTitle: $stateParams.name},
  });
```

I could also use the attribute **resolve** :

resolve: { title: 'Project page title' },

For stateParams value i could do that:

```
resolve:{
    pageTitle: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
      return $stateParams.name;
    }]
}
```

But then console.log($state.current.resolve.pageTitle); in my controller will return the entire function and not the result.

What would be the proper way to do that?

**UPDATE :**

The thing which i didn't mention is that i use angularJs with ES6 and i use a modular architecture. 
Therefore each component has its own scope.

You can check my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500779/angularjs-child-state-return-parent-view) to have a better idea about the modular architecture i'm using.

I'm building a breadcrumb grabbing the parent states (using the defined pageTitle). 
Therefore defining the page title name in each module would be perfect.

So i can decide if the page title would be a fixed value "My page title" or a stateParams value.

Maybe this is totally wrong and this should not be done that way. Let me know if it is the case.

Comment: May be you need to invoke the function?  Like console.log($state.current.resolve.pageTitle());

Comment: No this doesn't work :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a resolve like your example:

```
resolve:{
    pageTitle: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
        return $stateParams.name;
    }]
}
```

You'll need to inject `pageTitle` into your controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller', [
             'pageTitle',
    function (pageTitle) {

    }
]);
```

But i don't see how that is any different from injecting `$stateParams`:

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller', [
             '$stateParams',
    function ($stateParams) {

    }
]);
```

Comment: The thing which i didn't mention is that i use angularJs with ES6 and i use a modular architecture. Therefor each component has its own scope. I'm building a breadcrumb grabing the parent states (using the defined pageTitle). Therefor i would like to avoid having this logic in my breadcrumb component. Defining the page title name in each module would be perfect.

Comment: I get your point and i guess you are right. I checked this other post which seems to be exactly what i need to do. I can't manage to make it work yet with ES6 but at least it is a good hint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970406/how-to-make-automated-dynamic-breadcrumbs-with-angularjs-angular-ui-router